# How do I find kernel headers for a specific version of Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-headers

I need to write a kernel module for a Linux system as shown below.

```
# uname -a
Linux (none) 3.7.1 #1 SMP Mon Dec 23 06:07:19 PST 2013 i686 GNU/Linux

# cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 6
model name      : QEMU Virtual CPU version 2.5+
stepping        : 3
cpu MHz         : 2793.012
cache size      : 4096 KB
fdiv_bug        : no
hlt_bug         : no
f00f_bug        : no
coma_bug        : no
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 4
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep pge cmov mmx fxsr sse sse2 pni hypervisor
bogomips        : 5586.02
clflush size    : 32
cache_alignment : 32
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 32 bits virtual
power management:
```

The Linux box doesn't have kernel headers or the build system (`gcc`/`ld`) installed. Hence I need to set it up locally on my system. How can I find the kernel headers for this particular system? The [linux kernel on github](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tags)  has only the releases below, none of which matches exactly with the version (`v3.7.1`) of kernel installed there.

```
$ git tag | grep v3.7
v3.7
v3.7-rc1
v3.7-rc2
v3.7-rc3
v3.7-rc4
v3.7-rc5
v3.7-rc6
v3.7-rc7
v3.7-rc8
```

Comment: Actually you need to know *who* provided the kernel.  But if you don't care, [**this**](https://launchpad.net/linux/3.7/3.7.1) is good enough.  Likewise, [***this***](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/) may help.

Comment: The module needs to be written to solve a challenge. I guess I have no other means to know any more info. What I can conclude is it is running some sort of custom 32 bit kernel, tagged as v3.7.1, inside Qemu emulator.

Answer (score 2):

The archived sources are [at kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/) and are available as compressed tarballs and patchsets [in the CDN repository.](https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/) For version 3.7.1, the following tarballs are available:

- BZ2: https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/linux-3.7.1.tar.bz2
- GZ: https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/linux-3.7.1.tar.gz
- XZ: https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/linux-3.7.1.tar.xz
- Signature: https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/linux-3.7.1.tar.sign